# OAuth.popup() method not working in live and works on local host

Tags: javascript, twitter-oauth

I want to get twitter followers list for that I am using this code

```
OAuth.popup('twitter', function(err, res) {
            res.get('/1.1/followers/list.json?       count=500').done(function(data) {

            })
        });
```

this code is working fine on my local and not working on live server 
on the live server res in undefined 
please help me if you have any solution for that

Comment: got same problem, did you got any solution ?

Comment: no that's why i used php script for twitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After very long time spend on it got solution, Go to `oauth.io`, go to Dashboard and add Domains & URLs whitelist on your registered app on `oauth.io`, there is added 'localhost' by default, but you have to add yours.

Hope its works for you.